# How to understand Gitlab latency metric

Tags: gitlab, prometheus, grafana

Gitlab has a complete metrics dashboard running on a Grafana instance.
If I head to **Gitlab Omnibus - Overview**, within this dashboard, I can see a **Workhorse Latency panel** and if I step the mouse over, it shows me the count of requests on that specific bucket. So if I understand correctly, there are three requests in the bucket 10s - 30s in the image below.

[image]

However, when I inspect the data, I see these numbers in image 2, which do not make sense to me. What do these figures mean? How do I make sense of them?

On Prometheus I see the same numbers from the query:
*sum by (le)(rate(gitlab_workhorse_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{instance=~"localhost:9229"}[1m]))*

How can I count those numbers to make the same as what I'm seeing in the panel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [GitLab Prometheus metrics](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/prometheus/gitlab_metrics.html#metrics-available) does include indeed:

- `gitlab_rails_queue_duration_seconds` Measures latency between GitLab Workhorse forwarding a request to Rails
- `gitlab_transaction_rails_queue_duration_total`   Measures latency between GitLab Workhorse forwarding a request to Rails

I suppose the first graph display the number of queries which were within a certain latency limit, as reported by all the occurrences listed by the second image.